# RMI VS AppDynamics

Tags: jmx, appdynamics

JMX used for monitoring and managing the services/components & devices. My question is about monitoring,for the monitoring purpose do we have to change any code if we use JMX. If that is the case, App dynamics will solve this process without doing single line of code change ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't need to change anything in your code to capture JMX metrics except your Java Beans have to fulfill the Management Beans (MBeans) requirements you have to enable JMX monitoring in each Java process that should be monitored and the monitored system runs on Java 1.5 or later. See also [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Monitor+JMX+MBeans) and [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Monitor+JVMs). Then you can navigate to `Tiers & Nodes -> Select a tier -> JMX tab`